# Specified package com.oplus.internal.telephony under uid 1001 but it is not at com.android.server.appop.AppopsService

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

```
We have enabled R8 in Gradle properties and when we set minify enable to true the app gets crashed stating the below exception code.

In gradle.properties,
android.enableR8 = true
android.enableR8.fullMode=true
useProguard = true


In build.gradle,

 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
```

Exception :   java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package com.oplus.internal.telephony under uid 1001 but it is not
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.verifyAndGetBypass(AppOpsService.java:4791)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperationUnchecked(AppOpsService.java:3575)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperationImpl(AppOpsService.java:3563)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.access$4000(AppOpsService.java:223)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.lambda$noteOperation$4(AppOpsService.java:7769)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.apply(Unknown Source:33)
at com.android.server.policy.AppOpsPolicy.noteOperation(AppOpsPolicy.java:221)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService$CheckOpsDelegateDispatcher.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:7767)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.noteOperation(AppOpsService.java:3547)
at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub.onTransact(IAppOpsService.java:476)
at com.android.server.appop.OplusAppOpsService.onTransact(OplusAppOpsService.java:38)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1226)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1163)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Not related to minify, at least in my case. I think this is a bug. I submitted a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270386316).